# Webdriver do not support run as other user

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium webdriver on my web application for testing the speed of loading web sites. The scenario of my application is:
Click on link -> launch google web browser -> execute script on it.
All that work fine. The problem now when I move this project on remote computer in order to let's users testing the application via public url, chrome browser is not launched on their side but only in the remote computer.

This is what I tried

```
public static String driverpath = "C:\\Drivers";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverpath
                    + "\\chromedriver.exe");

        Webriver    driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Could You explain what situation You want to see when your action take place ???

Comment: 41.224.45.48:8383/web2/template/template.xhtml  this my web application. On clicking on site 1 you should see chrome browser, but it launched on my remote computer. Is it clear ?

Answer (score 0):

chrome.exe location in ur pc and in remote pc is not same. That's why in remote pc chrome is not opening. To run chrome driver on remote pc, first u have to connect it with ssh(secure shell) or any other. Than put ur chrome driver in ur project resource path. and than use this path .

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",CHROME_DRIVER_PATH_UR_PROJECT_RESOURCE_FOLDER);
```

Comment: Is secure shell important for making webdriver executes on client.
I changed the code as you said:  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
     getClass().getResource("/chromedriver.exe").toString()); but it still the same problem

Comment: U must have to connect with the remote pc...without this u can not execute